# A function in terms of trigonometric ratios

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

> Given the function $$f(x) = \frac { 1-\sin2x+\cos2x }{ 2\cos2x }$$
>   find the value of $8\cdot f(11)f(43)$.

I found the answer to be $4$.

May I know if the answer is right?

Comment: Dont you have a calculator?

Comment: I tried i get about 3.9999999978 Which is close enough to 4 but to be sure i decided to get a second opinion

Comment: That error  of the order of $10^{-10}$ is due to your calculator's memory limit..

Comment: So i guess its right

Comment: @PHPirate next time when you edit a post (which is a very good thing, especially if the question is almost unreadable) you can use $\sin(\cdot)$ instead $sin(\cdot)$, it renders it in math mode and looks much better, cheers and keep up the good work!

Comment: @sidt36 are you using radians or degrees?

Comment: degrees.......However i find it does not affect the end result

Comment: @sidt36 well, the thing is that $\cos(2\cdot 45 \mathrm{deg})=\cos(90 \mathrm{deg})=0$ and therefore $f(45)$ would not be defined...

Comment: Its is f(43) not 45

Comment: Your question is telling us something else.

Answer (score 2):

Although the function is undefined at $x=45^\circ$ it is a removeable discontinuity.

\begin{equation}
  f(x) = \frac { 1-\sin2x+\cos2x }{ 2\cos2x }
\end{equation}

So

\begin{equation}
\frac { 1-\sin2x+\cos2x }{ 2\cos2x }=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1-2\sin x\cos x+\cos^2x-\sin^2x}{\cos^2x-\sin^2x}\right)
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1-2\sin x\cos x+\cos^2x-\sin^2x}{\cos^2x-\sin^2x}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{(\cos x-\sin x)^2+(\cos x-\sin x)(\cos x+\sin x)}{(\cos x-\sin x)(\cos x+\sin x)}\right)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
f(x)=\frac{\cos x}{\cos x+\sin x}=\frac{1}{1+\tan x} \text{ for }\cos2x\ne0
\end{equation}

So the discontinuity at $x=45^\circ$ is removeable.

Using the version with the discontinuity removed gives

\begin{equation}
8\cdot\left(\frac{1}{1+\tan11^\circ}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1+\tan45^\circ} \right)=3.3490
\end{equation}

Since the questioner has changed the second angle from $45^\circ$ to $43^\circ$ the answer changes to

\begin{equation}
8\cdot\left(\frac{1}{1+\tan11^\circ}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1+\tan43^\circ} \right)=3.4660
\end{equation}